# How to fix this error: Nested forms are not allowed

Tags: html, forms

I have this code in my open source script:

```
<form id="thisform" method="post">
    <h2>{#Login#}</h2>
    <p class="right-text-al-rtl">{#Login_Have_Account#}</p>
    <form action="{$URL_login}" method="post">  
        <strong>{#Username#}/{#Email#}:</strong><br />
        <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="{if isset($login_username)}{$login_username}{/if}" tabindex="1" /><br />

        <strong>{#Password#}:</strong><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" tabindex="2" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="processlogin" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{if isset($get.return)}{$get.return}{/if}"/>
        <div class="login-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="{#LoginButton#}" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="4" />
        </div>
        <div class="login-remember">
            <input type="checkbox" class="col-sm-offset-2" name="persistent" tabindex="3" /> {#Login_Remember#}
        </div>
    </form>
</form>
```

The programmer of this script used two forms, one inside the other. This is not correct, but how can I fix this error and update my open source script?

Comment: What do you need the outer form for? Can you just remove it?

Comment: as I told before I don't know programming well. can you tell me? this two form is related to each other or not, or can I remove it? if I remove first form tag, every things work fine? after removing first form tag, my login form work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer `form` tag has no submit button, so **based on this snippet** it is safe to remove the outer form. To do this remove the `<form id...` line and the last `</form>` tag.

However, note that because the form carries an `id`, it is possible that it is being targeted by either CSS or Javascript in a way that is impossible to predict without seeing the entire codebase. The best thing to do is to remove it and test it for any regressions.

Comment: thank you, if I search for this id and found any thing else, what am I doing?

Comment: If you find something in a `.css` file it is likely that it will affect how your form is being displayed. If it is in a `.js` file there is code trying to interact with it. Otherwise, you're probably ok? Again, the best way to know is to try it and find out.

Comment: I remove outer form tag and users can login on website like before, thanks a lot Nathaniel Ford.